# How to show v-progress-liner vertically

Tags: vuetify.js

Haii could Any one help me I'm trying to make progress bar vertically. but it show in horizontally.

```
<v-progress-linear class="bar" :value="20"></v-progress-linear>

.bar
    {
        width:100%;
        display:block;        
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:12px; 
        background-color:#bb9319;
        color:#fff;       
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const config = {
    width: '75px',
    height: '160px',
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="battery-icon-wrapper">
    <div class="battery-bar">
      <VProgressLinear
        :model-value="40"
        :color="success"
        :height="config.width"
        rounded
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.battery-icon-wrapper {
  width: v-bind('config.width');
  height: v-bind('config.height');
  margin: 0 auto;

  .battery-bar {
    width: v-bind('config.height');
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
}
</style>
```

### Quick explanation

- set the height of the bar to the required width
- rotate the bar with CSS around the top left corner (this will make the beginning of the bar at the bottom)
- move it on the X-axis (this will adjust it vertically)
- make the dimensions of `.battery-icon-wrapper` equal to the required end result dimensions
- to position the vertical bar use the `.battery-icon-wrapper` in my example I just centered it horizontally

Answer (score -1):

You can add the css property `transform: rotate(90deg);` or `transform: rotate(-90deg);` depending on if you want the progress bar to progress up or down